# Magento2: order data issue

Tags: magento2, orders

In `response` variable, I am getting the last product only; not getting all products but in my log file, I am getting all products.

Here is my code:

```
class SalesOrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $date;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date)
   { 
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
      $this->date = $date;
      $this->orderData = $orderData;
   }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $enable=$this->scopeConfig->getValue('abc/orderconfig/mkt_order_integration', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        if($enable){ 
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $status = 0;
            $name='';
            $data['Email'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
            $data['FirstName'] = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
            $data['LastName'] = $order->getCustomerLastName();
            $response= $this->orderData->orderData($data,$status,$name);  
            $res= json_decode($response, true); 
            if($res['success']==1){ 
                $productobjectname= $this->scopeConfig->getValue('abc/orderconfig/productcustomobject', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
                $orderobjectname= $this->scopeConfig->getValue('abc/orderconfig/ordercustomobject', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
                $status = 1;   
                foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
                    if($item->getData()){ 
                    $digits = 3;
                    $rndno= rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
                    $cname= $productobjectname;
                    $pdata['emailAddress'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
                    $pdata['orderId']= $order->getIncrementId();
                    $pdata['incrementId'] = $order->getIncrementId().$item->getProductId();
                    $pdata['productId'] = $item->getProductId();
                    $pdata['productName'] = $item->getName();
                    $pdata['productAmount'] = $item->getPrice();
                    $pdata['productSku'] = $item->getSku();
                    $pdata['productQty'] = (int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
                    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/orderData3.log');
                    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                    $logger->addWriter($writer);

                    $logger->info($pdata);  
                    $response = $this->orderData->orderData($pdata,$status,$cname); 
                   }
                }


            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Please check my code and guide me on how can I get all the products to the **`response`** variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/orderData3.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);  
$i = 0; 
$pdata = array();

foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
     if($item->getData()){ 
         $digits = 3;
         $rndno= rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
         $cname= $productobjectname;
         $pdata[$i]['emailAddress'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
         $pdata[$i]['orderId']= $order->getIncrementId();
         $pdata[$i]['incrementId'] = $order->getIncrementId();
         $pdata[$i]['productId'] = $item->getProductId();
         $pdata[$i]['productName'] = $item->getName();
         $pdata[$i]['productAmount'] = $item->getPrice();
         $pdata[$i]['productSku'] = $item->getSku();
         $pdata[$i]['productQty'] = (int)$item->getQtyOrdered();      
         $i++;

         $logger->info($pdata);  
       }
    }
$response = $this->orderData->orderData($pdata,$status,$cname);
```

Comment: I am getting all the products in logs but its sending only last product in response

Comment: Modified my answer, try this.

Comment: what you have changed?

Comment: See, I have added $i variable and increase value every time end of the foreach loop and declared an array before the loop. At last set the array value to $response variable.

Comment: Moved the $response variable after the foreach loop end.

Comment: getting issue with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102488/discussion-between-shiwani-and-indranil-maity).

Comment: getting error: A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.

Comment: If this answer helped. Can you please confirm the answer, So other developer can use this. Thanks!

Comment: no with this i was getting error